# testing ejabberd modules

Tags: erlang, ejabberd

I have written some ejabberd modules using behaviour gen_mod. These modules will be part of ejabberd supervision tree and perform some tasks.

I would like to know what is the common way to test such kind of modules. I googled a bit, and the only useful resource was [this github project](https://github.com/cstar/ejabberd_testing).

Can you tell me what is the best way to test ejabberd modules?

Answer (score 2):

I will recommend using [Escalus](https://github.com/esl/escalus) if you are looking to verify correctness of ejabberd modules. Directly from Escalus README:

> Escalus is Erlang library for convenient testing of XMPP servers. It's
>   intended to be used with Common Test.
>
> Escalus is aimed at checking correctness of XMPP server behaviour, in
>   contrast to tools such as Tsung which are about stress testing, and
>   don't verify correctness.

Comment: how can i find resourses on escalus and ejabberd components scenarios?

Comment: Currently there is a test suite with getting started documentation https://github.com/esl/escalus/blob/master/docs/intro.md that comes bundled with escalus, you should try to get through it first. Once done, try to simply extend on the same. Probably someone (may be me) should do an exhaustive blog post on escalus.

Comment: i have seen those tutorials, but there is no examples about iq stanzas between internal component and user